# Unable to find device with the name in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have been working on xamarin for a while, it was working before, today I started getting deployment fail error and then I uninstalled xamarin android player (XAP) and reinstalled it again. When I click to build and deploy the solution, then I have started getting the following error.

[image]

But I have this device installed in XAP.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked Virtual Box does not functioning properly then I have restarted the machine and now it is working.